# Call SQL procedure not working when call with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to call a mySQL procedure in a long query, so I can save every other code and optimize the query.
The query is **running as expected if I run the query with MYSQL, via phpMyAdmin or Dbeaver**, but when I try to run the query with PDO and PHP, it doesn't call the procedure. Doesn't run return any errors too.

Here is the query:

```
SET @dossier_id = ?;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTable AS SELECT * FROM dossier WHERE DossierID = @dossier_id;
ALTER TABLE TempTable MODIFY DossierID INT null;
UPDATE TempTable SET DossierID = null, `Status` = 0, dossier_type = 2, created_DealerID = 10, created_dealervestigingID = 1, dossier_id_duplicate = @dossier_id;
UPDATE TempTable SET LastUpdate = current_timestamp();
INSERT INTO dossier (SELECT * FROM TempTable);
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); -- WE DONT USE THAT, BECAUSE OF SESSION[DID]
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTable as SELECT * FROM mt_car where DossierID = @dossier_id;
ALTER TABLE TempTable MODIFY mt_carID INT null;
UPDATE TempTable SET mt_carID = null, DossierID = @last_id;
INSERT INTO mt_car (SELECT * FROM TempTable);
SET @last_car_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTable as SELECT * FROM mt_car_details where DossierID = @dossier_id;
ALTER TABLE TempTable MODIFY mt_car_detailsID INT null;
UPDATE TempTable SET mt_car_detailsID = null, DossierID = @last_id;
INSERT INTO mt_car_details (SELECT * FROM TempTable);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS WhileLoop;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE WhileLoop()
BEGIN

SET @counter= 1;
set @arr = '../crm/library/fotoupload/uploads/1649084850_817.jpg,../crm/library/fotoupload/uploads/1649084850_818.jpg,../crm/library/fotoupload/uploads/1649084850_819.jpg,../crm/library/fotoupload/uploads/1649084850_820.jpg,../crm/library/fotoupload/uploads/1649084850_821.jpg';
SET @arr_length = (length(@arr) - length(replace(@arr, ',','')) + 1);
SET @arr_length = (length(@arr) - length(replace(@arr, ',','')) + 1);
WHILE @counter < @arr_length
DO
    SET @temp = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@arr,',',@counter),',',-1);
    INSERT INTO atautofoto
    (DossierID, vehicle_id, Foto, fotosoort, foto_nr, foto_ref, originated_foto, herkomst)  
    VALUES (@last_id, @last_car_id, @temp, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1 );
    SET @counter  = @counter  + 1;
END WHILE;       
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL WhileLoop();


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTable as SELECT * FROM atvoertuig2018_eigenopties where DossierID = @dossier_id;
ALTER TABLE TempTable MODIFY voertuig2018_eigenoptiesID INT null;
UPDATE TempTable SET voertuig2018_eigenoptiesID = null;
UPDATE TempTable SET DossierID = @last_id;
INSERT INTO atvoertuig2018_eigenopties (SELECT * FROM TempTable);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTable as SELECT * FROM tabel where DossierID = @dossier_id;
ALTER TABLE TempTable MODIFY TabelID INT null;
SET @tabel_status = (SELECT Omschrijving FROM conversie WHERE Soort = 'Status' AND Nummer = 0 AND language_type = 2);
UPDATE TempTable SET TabelID = null, DossierID = @last_id, `Status` = @tabel_status;
INSERT INTO tabel (SELECT * FROM TempTable);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;

INSERT INTO inkoop (DossierID) VALUES (@last_id);
INSERT INTO verkoop (DossierID) VALUES (@last_id);
INSERT INTO schouwing (DossierID) VALUES (@last_id);
INSERT INTO transport_order (DossierID) VALUES (@last_id);
INSERT INTO inlevermoment (DossierID) VALUES (@last_id);
INSERT INTO marge (DossierID) VALUES (@last_id);


--    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTable as SELECT * FROM newcar where DossierID = @dossier_id;
--    ALTER TABLE TempTable MODIFY newcarID INT null;
--    UPDATE TempTable SET newcarID = null, DossierID = @last_id, ;
--    INSERT INTO newcar (SELECT * FROM TempTable);
--    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;

CREATE TEMPORARY table if not EXISTS TempTable SELECT * FROM atform_answers where DossierID = @dossier_id;
ALTER TABLE TempTable MODIFY atform_answersID INT null;
UPDATE TempTable SET atform_answersID = null;
UPDATE TempTable SET DossierID = @last_id;
INSERT INTO atform_answers (SELECT * FROM TempTable);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable; "
```

Here's how I run the query with PHP:
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$dossier_id]);

Expectations:
Run the query and run the procedure inside the query, and insert data.

Actually after call the procedure, nothing happens, the other inserts doesn't work too.
This happens only for the inserts down the procedure call and only when I run the query via php.

I'm not actually sure if it's the right way to use procedures, but I didn't find a way to use loop in mySQL and it works, if I run the query not with php with the website

Comment: That's not a query. That's a dump that consists of several dozen queries. Queries are meant to be run one by one when executed via database API calls.

Comment: Doing string parsing and looping in SQL is terribly clumsy and inefficient.  Either find a single SQL do do all the work, or move the work to PHP.

Comment: Do not use PDO to issue more than one statement at a time.  Create procs from the mysql commandline tool, not an application.

Comment: I don't usually use multiple queries like that. If I use PHP for this I need to fetch many times for a few values. I don't know why but it gets very slowly with PHP.
I need the loop in SQL because I copy files and I still don't have the ID that I want to insert with and 20 INSERTs with PHP are very slowly /still don't know why/. The problem was with the delimiters, I should not use them in the PDO. Now it works very fast and stable. 
@RickJames Is there any reasons, that I didn't read not to use PDO to run a queries like that?